# Zipping a Folder end up in error depending on 1 file

Tags: xml, go, zip, libreoffice

I've got a Function to Zip a folder containing LibreOffice Data. (see at the bottom)

When I run it with one content.xml template it works well and return me this

```
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.786 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/META-INF
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.786 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/META-INF/manifest.xml
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.786 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.786 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures/10000000000001600000012D9E307CB2879DFB48.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.786 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures/10000000000001CD000000748F8655D91EA6B1A8.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.787 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures/100002010000026C00000445EABC4B9AD8977F8C.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.791 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Thumbnails
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.791 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.793 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/content.xml
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.793 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/manifest.rdf
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.794 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/meta.xml
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.794 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/mimetype
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.794 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/settings.xml
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:54:57.794 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/styles.xml
```

BUT when I run it with another template it just error out

```
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.755 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/META-INF
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.755 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/META-INF/manifest.xml
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.756 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.756 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures/10000000000001600000012D9E307CB2879DFB48.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.756 INFO Processing ./documents/bon/Pictures/10000000000001CD000000748F8655D91EA6B1A8.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.758 INFO 2
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.758 INFO &{0xc0000b8000 [0xc000423a00 0xc000423a70] 0xc00007e0f0 false map[]  <nil>}
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.758 INFO Pictures/10000000000001CD000000748F8655D91EA6B1A8.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.758 INFO ./documents/bon/Pictures/10000000000001CD000000748F8655D91EA6B1A8.png
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.758 INFO <nil>
app_1         | 2020-08-20 07:56:57.758 INFO invalid argument
app_1         | 2020/08/20 07:56:57 http: panic serving 172.18.0.1:42280: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
app_1         | goroutine 191 [running]:
app_1         | net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00021a0a0)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1772 +0x139
app_1         | panic(0x94bfa0, 0xe2ddb0)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x3e3
app_1         | aptacrm/util.processFolder(0xc00007e050, 0xc000516de0, 0x19, 0xc000028940, 0x9)
app_1         |         /go/src/aptacrm/util/Zip.go:47 +0x3fd
app_1         | aptacrm/util.processFolder(0xc00007e050, 0x9e26f9, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0)
app_1         |         /go/src/aptacrm/util/Zip.go:31 +0x340
app_1         | aptacrm/util.ZipFolder(0x9e26f9, 0x10, 0xc0001c21c0, 0x63)
app_1         |         /go/src/aptacrm/util/Zip.go:14 +0x18b
app_1         | aptacrm/routes/RestfullAPI.exportBon(0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008faf00)
app_1         |         /go/src/aptacrm/routes/RestfullAPI/bons.go:236 +0x8af
app_1         | net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa02870, 0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008faf00)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2012 +0x44
app_1         | aptacrm/routes.Middleware.func1(0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008faf00)
app_1         |         /go/src/aptacrm/routes/init.go:37 +0x80
app_1         | net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000eac0, 0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008faf00)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2012 +0x44
app_1         | github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc000218000, 0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008fad00)
app_1         |         /go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0xe2
app_1         | net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xe40600, 0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008fad00)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2387 +0x1a5
app_1         | net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0002260e0, 0xaafd00, 0xc000226000, 0xc0008fad00)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2807 +0xa3
app_1         | net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00021a0a0, 0xab0dc0, 0xc00024cd00)
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1895 +0x86c
app_1         | created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
app_1         |         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2933 +0x35c
```

the file `content.xml` is the same on each points but the only change is it's size

```
Normal    version: -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  43580 Aug 20 09:59 content.xml
Defective version: -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  43416 Aug 20 09:56 content.xml
```

Do someone perhaps know what is happening ?

The function used

```golang
package util

import (
    "os"
    "archive/zip"
    "io/ioutil"
    "aptacrm/vars"
)

func ZipFolder(folder string, output string) {
    var outFile, _ = os.Create(output)
    defer outFile.Close()
    var writer = zip.NewWriter(outFile)
    processFolder(writer, folder, "")

    writer.Close()

}

func processFolder(writer *zip.Writer, basePath string, baseInZip string) {
    var files, _ = ioutil.ReadDir(basePath)

    for _, file := range files {
        var realFilePath = basePath + file.Name()
        var zipFilePath = baseInZip + file.Name()
        vars.Logger.Info("Processing", realFilePath)

        var isDir = file.IsDir()

        if isDir {
            processFolder(writer, realFilePath + "/", baseInZip + file.Name() + "/")
        } else {
            var fileData, e1 = ioutil.ReadFile(realFilePath)
            if e1 != nil {
                vars.Logger.Info("1")
                vars.Logger.Info(e1.Error())
            }
            var fileWriter, e2 = writer.Create(zipFilePath)
            if e2 != nil {
                vars.Logger.Info("2")
                vars.Logger.Info(writer)
                vars.Logger.Info(zipFilePath)
                vars.Logger.Info(realFilePath)
                vars.Logger.Info(fileWriter)
                vars.Logger.Info(e2.Error())
            }
            var _, e3 = fileWriter.Write(fileData)
            if e3 != nil {
                vars.Logger.Info("3")
                vars.Logger.Info(e3.Error())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionnal informations:

- Go Version 1.15.0 via the golang docker container `golang:alpine`
- vars.Logger is `stdlog.GetFromFlags()` from `github.com/alexcesaro/log/stdlog` library

Comment: You have a non-nil error on `writer.Create("Pictures/10000000000001CD000000748F8655D91EA6B1A8.png")`, you should check where it comes from and definitely not ignore it. Instead, return the error to the higher functions, don't just proceed. `archive/zip` does not currently return "invalid argument", but we don't know which version of Go you're running.

Comment: I am using golang 1.15 via their Docker container golang:alpine + I added a `continue` after the line `vars.Logger.Info(e2.Error())` to see if it was only one file, but each files after will error in the same way

Comment: A plain "invalid argument" tends to come from syscalls. Check the output file. Also check the other errors you are ignoring (`os.Create` and `ioutil.ReadDir`).

Comment: Thanks ! `os.Create` was the function call to error out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4966953/marc) for giving me the good direction !

The problem came from the naming of my output file, it contained `/` in it and `os.Create` returned an error containing all the indication I needed to fix it !